# Get value from assoc array, returns oe?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I've got an array (provided by an api), of which I try to get the ID form an establishment.
I put the result in a `$decodeArray = json_decode($result);` and that I put that result in a `var_dump();`
Which returns:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["ok"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["establishments"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
      ["level"]=>
      string(5) "admin"
      ["establishment"]=>
      object(stdClass)#3 (5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(36) "0b246874-2c53-11e8-8fb6-001a4aa8ea16"
        ["name"]=>
        string(9) "robinsons"
        ["address"]=>
        string(24) "Belfast northern ireland"
        ["lat"]=>
        float(54.594869)
        ["lng"]=>
        float(-5.933954)
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
      ["level"]=>
      string(5) "admin"
      ["establishment"]=>
      object(stdClass)#5 (5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(36) "1e95af3a-2ce7-11e8-8fb6-001a4aa8ea16"
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "reimink"
        ["address"]=>
        string(13) "dorpsstraat 6"
        ["lat"]=>
        float(123.123)
        ["lng"]=>
        float(-74.99)
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
      ["level"]=>
      string(5) "admin"
      ["establishment"]=>
      object(stdClass)#7 (5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(36) "3d1e500b-2c4d-11e8-8fb6-001a4aa8ea16"
        ["name"]=>
        string(14) "kelly's cellar"
        ["address"]=>
        string(24) "Belfast northern ireland"
        ["lat"]=>
        float(54.599508)
        ["lng"]=>
        float(-5.93216)
      }
    }
    [3]=>
    object(stdClass)#8 (2) {
      ["level"]=>
      string(5) "admin"
      ["establishment"]=>
      object(stdClass)#9 (5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(36) "75987f56-2de4-11e8-8fb6-001a4aa8ea16"
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "reimink"
        ["address"]=>
        string(12) "graslanden 2"
        ["lat"]=>
        float(3456.33)
        ["lng"]=>
        int(-1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I try to echo all the items like the 'id' and 'name' from every establishment.
I tried reaching the values, but can't quite seem to get it right.

```
 foreach ($decodeArray as $item => $key)
 { 
 echo $item['establishments'][0]['establishment']['name'];
 }
```

The above foreach loop seems to be the closest I can get, but it only returns "oe" (no clue where that originates from).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pass `true` as the second argument for `json_decode`. That should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `true` to `json_decode` to get an array, but then you need to look at the nesting:

```
foreach ($decodeArray['establishments'] as $values)
{ 
    echo $values['establishment']['name'];
}
```

To do it with the objects you have it would be:

```
foreach ($decodeArray->establishments as $values)
{ 
    echo $values->establishment->name;
}
```

The `o` and `e` come from the first letter of the only two top level properties: *"ok"* and *"establishments"*.  Because of the way you're trying to access them the `0` is treated as a string index and you are operating on the property name.

Comment: Thanks, this works (: Also like it that you put a solution for the objects.

Answer (score 1):

You try to access the data structure using the array syntax (with square brackets) but it is not an array.

Pass `TRUE` as the second argument to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to ask it to decode the JSON to arrays (not objects) and the code in the `foreach` loop will work as expected.

```
$decodeArray = json_decode($result, TRUE);
```

Comment: awwww i was 10 seconds late to give the answer :(
anyway, in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) there is a quite good explanation about this.